# IIS site started but not working

Tags: iis

I sometimes have a problem after a server reboot one of the sites in IIS does not working.

When browsing Internet Explorer immediately displays 'Navigation to the webpage was cancelled'.

I don't see any errors in the IIS file logs (although I forgot to check the event viewer, and currently do not have access to the server).

The site says it is started, and checking with netstat says the System process has the port allocated. Restart doesn't help.

What does help however is stopping the site, changing the port, starting the site, stopping the site, changing the port back to the original value and finally starting the site. So it seems unlikely there is a port conflict.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967941

Answer (score 1):

I got access to the event viewer after all and saw some warnings concerning SSL. There was also an SChannel error.

It will probably be a problem with the certificate, as described in this article
http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate

If I can reproduce, I will try to follow these steps.